# SQL query to select rows where the year is between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Given a Table with from_date date and a to_date date column, I want to select all sets of data where an year, for example 2007, is the year of one of the dates or both or is in between the two dates.

How can i achieve this using mySQL?

Table:

```
create Table Articleprice
(`ArtikelpreisNR` int, `ArtikelNR` int, `from_Date` date, `to_date` date, `price` int);
```

Example Testdata

```
insert into Articleprice
(`ArtikelPreisNR`, `ArtikelNR`,`from_Date`, `to_Date` ,`price`)

values (1, 1, '2006-7-04', '2008-7-04', 10);
```

SQL:
This is returning only the ones, when from_date and to_date = 2007

```
SELECT
MIN(price)
FROM  Articleprice
WHERE Articleprice.from_Date >= '2007/01/01' and Articleprice.to_Date <= '2007/12/31';
```

What do I need to do in order to solve my Case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you build complete dates using the year. For 2007, the dates would be `2007-01-01` and `2007-12-31` (assuming that end dates are inclusive).

Next you use [overlapping dates query](http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2012/06/sql-query-overlapping-date-ranges.html) to find all rows that (i) end inside (ii) start inside (iii) contain or (iv) contained within the year 2007. The query is simply:

```
SELECT * FROM Articleprice
WHERE '2007-12-31' >= from_Date AND to_date > '2007-01-01'
```

Comment: gotta go deeper in the overlapping dates queries hence i need it for my exams. Thanks for giving me some work to do ;)

Comment: Bug:  First inequality needs to be ">="

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your dates are actually dates and not strings, you need to use the proper date format in your query: YYYY-MM-DD not YYY/MM/DD:

```
WHERE Articleprice.from_Date >= '2007-01-01' and Articleprice.to_Date <= '2007-12-31';
```

Comment: This does not return rows where, for example, from date is `2006-7-04` and to date is `2008-7-04` (see sample data, OP thinks it should be returned).

Comment: Update your question to show actual table data and structure. There's something you're noty telling us that's important as this *will*work under normal circumstances.

Comment: @johnconde it´s all in my Question, Salman A figured it out already, but thanks anyway i got my working solution now ;)